# How to get the tags of the products from a category?

Tags: php, mysql, magento, tags

I have a few categories with products in each of them. Each product has some tags assigned to them.

On the category view, I want to display all the tags ONLY the products from that category are having.

I can get all the tags from the shop, and all the products from that category, but how can I take just the tags of the products from that category?

I was thinking to iterate all the products and all the tags and check if each product has that tag and build a list with them (I don't know if it's optimal).
Can I check somehow if a product has a specific tag? Or is there any other way to get all the tags of the products I have in my category?

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

First get the product list of a specfic category using category id. Then iterate thorugh all the products to display their tags in the view